# Pitch shift in hearing after wisdom teeth removal

Tags: sensation, hearing, senses

Yesterday I had my wisdom teeth removed. This morning, when I heard our phone ringing, it sounded a little lower-pitched than usual (I have perfect pitch). Sure enough, when I opened FL Studio (music-making software) and loaded up one of my projects, I had to adjust the master pitch up by about 20 cents for it to sound "in-tune". What could cause this shift in pitch perception?

Comment: The change in blood flow to, or damage to the cochlea by vibrational trauma (drilling) were implicated in a hearing loss case [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19927688) after some dental surgery. You'll want to consult a physician, however, for any of your worries. If this is a personal case, we cannot provide medical assistance, nor do we have enough information about your or your procedure to begin consideration.

Comment: Because it's not really hearing *loss*, I'm not too concerned about it. I'm mostly just curious as to what could cause a shift in pitch perception.

Comment: Temporary swelling or edema from the extraction would be my assumption.

Comment: Perfect pitch with respect to what note? (A440?) Also, how broad is the supposed pitch shift? I find it rather hard to believe that swelling can cause a logarithmic pitch shift across the entire audible spectrum.

Comment: @MarchHo yes, A440. And as far as I can tell, it affects my entire hearing range, although I haven't thoroughly tested it.

Comment: Does it affect pure notes or only chords? I'm not sure what tests you've done or what perfect pitch is like(I don't have it and I can't really imagine how it works), but my very first guess would be that higher pitches are more attenuated by your newly detoothed skull, so higher harmonics sound quieter and the overall sound is lower. That would work on a ringing phone but should work less noticeably on pure tones.

Comment: I once had an ear infection that, when done, left that ear's perceived pitch shifted by about a quarter tone, which really messed up listening to music (google ToneTester and you'll see the testing app I wrote afterwards). I recovered after a few months.

Comment: I just had my wisdom teeth removed, and I'm experiencing the same thing. What I used to hear as 440 for A is now actually at around 450 - 460. When I hear people talking, I don't notice a difference, but when I was tuning my violin today it felt kind of off. Same with the Discord sounds when people left or joined calls; they sounded lower pitch than I was used to.